# How can you update a shared Boolean variable realtime between two threads?

Tags: multithreading, android-asynctask, while-loop

I am trying to call a thread to play sounds using a loop. It seems to call and play ok.

However, I want to be able to allow the user to exit the loop when they click the 'Pause' button. I've setup boolean variable "PauseClicked" to allow this.

The problem I think I am having - I don't know how to update the "PauseClicked" variable from my main thread. Do you know how I can update this variable from the main thread at the same while the loop is running?

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated. I've spent a lot of time unsuccessfully on this. The particular code I'm unsure about is below (the attempt to update the variable is on the third last line):

```
// Import statements
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 boolean PauseClicked = false;

 // .... Other variables and onCreate....


    public void whenPlayClicked(View view) {
        new LongOperation().execute("");

    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            //Setup playing variables
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            float curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float leftVolume = curVolume / maxVolume;
            float rightVolume = curVolume / maxVolume;
            int priority = 1;
            int no_loop = 0;
            float normal_playback_rate = 1f;

            //temporary sleep counters
            int blueSleep = (BlueCount * 1000);
            int greenSleep = (GreenCount * 1000);
            int redSleep = (RedCount * 1000);
            int orangeSleep = (OrangeCount * 1000);
            int bellSleep = 4000;
            int cyclesPlayed = 0;

            // Loop - loop until either 1) all cycles have been played. (i.e repeat number of times selected from Spinner).
            //  or 2)Pause button is clicked.
            for (PauseClicked = false; (cyclesPlayed < cycleCount) && (PauseClicked == false); cyclesPlayed++) {
                if (blueSleep > 0) {
                    soundPool.play(blueSoundID, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);
                    SystemClock.sleep(blueSleep);
                }

                if (greenSleep > 0) {
                    soundPool.play(greenSoundID, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);
                    SystemClock.sleep(greenSleep);
                }

                if (redSleep > 0) {
                    soundPool.play(redSoundID, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);
                    SystemClock.sleep(redSleep);
                }

                if (orangeSleep > 0) {
                    soundPool.play(orangeSoundID, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);
                    SystemClock.sleep(orangeSleep);
                }
          //      CheckForPause();
            }

            if (TotCount > 0) {
                SystemClock.sleep(bellSleep);
                soundPool.play(bellSoundID, 0.05F, 0.05F, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);
                SystemClock.sleep(bellSleep);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView2.setText("We are returning from call to ASynch task.");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }


    public void whenPauseClicked(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All sounds were paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        PauseClicked = true;
        soundPool.autoPause();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not good at java, but I guess `&& (PauseClicked == false)` is optimized out because of `PauseClicked = false`. How about trying `volatile boolean PauseClicked = false;`? (I don't know java much, but I guess.)

Comment: Hi Ikh - I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Thanks anyway,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AtomicBoolean, this kind of boolean used in your case - when multiple threads accessing it. 
Try to change the definition of PauseClicked to

```
AtomicBoolean PauseClicked = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

In your code, use it's get and set methods when you're trying to access it. 
Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Reuven - I've changed PauseClicked to an AtomicBoolean and using the get and set methods - it does appear to be updating as I needed. Thankyou very much for your help on this. Regards,

Comment: Anytime bud, glad to hear it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` should be fine in this case, unless you are performing compound actions (however, I don't see any, but you might want to use them in some code that you aren't providing), such as those provided in `AtomicBoolean`, which you would use instead.

Since volatile booleans guarantee atomic writes and reads, you should be set with that. They are also *slightly* faster than AtomicBoolean, but the difference is <1 nanosecond, which is negligible.